# How to tell log4j that there is no web container?

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, log4j2

We have an Eclipse/SWT client and we are using log4j2. We get the following log entry

```
2020-09-24 07:17:01,769 main INFO Log4j appears to be running in a Servlet environment, but there's no log4j-web module available. If you want better web container support, please add the log4j-web JAR to your web archive or server lib directory.
```

The reason for that is, that we import the servlet-api to make use of [open feign](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign) for the REST communication to the server. The interfaces used by open feign have servlet-api annotations.

So removing servlet-api as suggested in [Why Log4j thinks my project run in Servlet Environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37344431/why-log4j-thinks-my-project-run-in-servlet-environment/37345105) to get rid of the message does not work for us.

This is really annoying, since log4j2 fills our logs with this.

How can we get rid of this message?

Comment: Please check your app dependency - may be servlet jar is added via some third party dependency ?

Comment: As stated in the question, the jar is there on purpose. The question is how to get rid of the message without removing the jar.

Answer (score 0):

Since this log is generated by the log4j2 itself, you may want to raise the log4j's internal loglevel from **INFO** to **WARN**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">

<Appenders>
...
```

..